# How to set the current device `secondaryDeviceType` for a WifiP2pDevice?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

For every WiFiP2pDevice, there is an internal field called `secondaryDeviceType`. It's a string. I'm looking for a way to update it so that when other devices find the said device, they should be able to see the manually set value of `secondaryDeviceType`.

I've tried to do it with reflections and called `wifiP2pDevice.update()` but it didn't work. I couldn't see the change from other devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer this question for anyone in the future. It's just not possible. Turns out that the WiFi-Direct API for Android doesn't allow that level of flexibility.